# Firefox Clippings extension no longer working Salesforce Support Console Comments

Tags: service-cloud-console, service-console, firefox

I use firefox with the Clippings Extension to paste commonly used text into comments in Salesforce. Mostly I use the Console view. A few months ago this stopped working on Windows 10. Last week it stopped working on Mac OSX 10.11.6.
I currently use firefox ESR 45, though this did not coincide with any firefox upgrade. Clippings is version 5.1, but started with the previous version.
All other applications I use work fine, as do other views in Salesforce.

It is most frustrating as of all the ways to work with cases in Salesforce the Console is the most efficient and comprehensive. And Clippings is a great tool for remembering text that needs to be repeated, without overwriting the paste buffer.

So what have Salesforce done in the console to block Clippings?
Anyone have a work around?
Anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Are you getting any Developer Console errors when you try to paste something? You can go to the menu icon, then choose Developer > Web Console. Try your paste and see if you get any errors. I'm not sure if we can help you, but we'd certainly be willing to give it a go if we just had something to work off of.

Comment: Not a single item is logged in the console when using Clippings to insert some text. Same in the working and failing case.
I assume that Salesforce is in some way setting the input text box to block injected text, but only in the Console.

Comment: I found one new clue; if I use the Clippings shortcut key sequence alt+cmd+V (ctl+alt+V on Windows) in the Salesforce Console comment text box it says "donk", but is also blocked. Whereas this sequence also works fine if it is a text box I can inject text into using Clippings.
Still no errors.